# ASM's Frame class has no generic type

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

[ASM documentation (pdf)](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf) says, that `Frame` class has generic type, providing an example of usage: `Frame<BasicValue>`. (at p. 119, if needed)

When looking at the [source](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadasmall40sourcesjar.htm), we can see it's declaration like `Frame<V extends Value>`.

But for some reason, when in my project I specify maven dependencies,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
     <artifactId>asm-analysis</artifactId>
     <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or just load according artifacts manually from repository, attempt to use `Frame<...>` ends with error:

```
Type org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Frame doesn't have type parameters
```

And `Intellij IDEA` decompiler says `Frame` really has no ones.

The same issue takes place with `Analyzer` and `Interpreter` classes.

How can I beat that?

Comment: You cant download the jar and keep Generics. They optimize their downloads. You'll have to get the source and compile it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complementing an answer of @dejvuth:

[asm-debug-all](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm-debug-all) happens to be of Java 5.0 version and contains all generic types. Morever, it's binary compatible with plain asm library with no generics

Answer (score 2):

From [ASM FAQ](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html)

> **14. What is the earliest JDK required to use ASM?**
>
> ...
>
> The asm.util and asm.tree packages require JDK 1.2, ...

and [History](http://asm.ow2.org/history.html) of ASM 4.0 RC1

> generified the API to use generics and varargs. However, almost all jars are still small and 1.2 compatible.

Basically, when jarred, ASM optimizes the bytecode, which (among others) makes it backward-compatible with 1.2 by changing its major version to 46 (see `org.objectweb.asm.optimizer.ClassOptimizer`).

I guess there are two options available: use it without generics or compile the source by yourself.